# Adding a twig filter after page is loaded

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I run a twig filter for an image that's loaded through jQuery? 
Long story short: I have a username on my page on which people can click. 
That will get the user info through jQuery (together with the path to the profile photo)

Normally I load the images with a filter like this:

```
<img src="{{ '/relative/path/to/image.jpg' | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

I have loaded my image successfully with jQuery like this:

```
$(".profile-pic").attr("src", "/uploads/profilephotos/" + data['path']);
```

How do I continue from here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It obviously will not be possible to add a twig filter after page is loaded, because twig is actually php, so it will execute only on the server.

My guess is, you will have to get any processed profile data for images with jQuery. I believe you use ajax?

I guess a solution would be to make any additional controller actions, with which you can get any processed text data that you need. If you want an optimised / resized image, I suggest you store the image in multiple sizes after successful upload and return the path(s) to those images with a controller action, which you will use to make ajax request. That way, the images will be stored and will not be processed everytime on requests.

Or even better, if you can, you can also make the url in symfony like:

```
GET http://localhost/project/files/logo/1/thumb
```

Which returns a binary file, which will be your processed image. The images will be processed on every request, so it might be a little slower. Look for a tutorial on this if you need, it's in symfony2 project documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My original though was to create resized images of the original photo at upload but I thought of something else. I'll just use jQuery's load() function to load another twig template. I suppose that will work too? :)

Comment: I think it should, but why are you using jQuery for loading this anyway and what specific filter are you using? I hope it does not include base64 encoded image, because some browser have limitation of the data size. Anyway I think you would be better of with the solutions I provided above:)

Comment: I'm using jQuery to load userData because I'm showing a table with users on which a visitor can click to see more info without having to reload the screen. That info is being showed in a <div> on the right of the screen. I'm using the imagine_filter from https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle